# Printing a pdf file using javax.print

Tags: java, printing

Hey everyone , 
I'm facing a real problem here while trying to print a pdf file using java print .
The problem is that when i send the file to the printer using print() method with cute pdf the file is well printed but with a real printer it couldn't be done .
`

```
try{  
 File file = new File(toprint);
   InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

   DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;


   DocPrintJob job = p.createPrintJob();//p here is my printservice printer 
   HashPrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
   HashDocAttributeSet  ds=new HashDocAttributeSet();


   Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);

    job.print(doc, aset);
    }
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("An exception occured while printing the file "+ e);
}
```

`
I've tried it so many times but it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: What happens?  Do you get an exception?  If so please give us the stack trace.  Or do you simply not get anything printed?  Have you tried printing non-pdf files to this printer?

Comment: Never do something like this: System.out.println("An exception occured while printing the file "+ e);
Always do e.printStackTrace(), or don't catch the exception at all

Comment: Actually , i don't get any exception , everything goes well and the job is sent to the printer but it's only prints one blank page for pdf , and when i tried w word documents , it printed one line for each page containing only some ambiguous Symbole

Comment: wlegend, have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think your printer may not have support for pdf, in this case you will have to render it using a pdf renderer.

Look at http://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer and pageable print page.

If you find it helpful I will provide code samples.